# Any way to make await DataStore.save() faster?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, datastore

I am creating a react js web app that uses amplify datastore to access and modify database tables and entries.

```
            Object
                .entries(modelFields)
                .forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    if (typeof value === "string" && value.trim() === "") {
                        modelFields[key] = undefined;
                    }
                });
            
            setLoading(true);
            console.log("Attempting Save. ");
            await DataStore.save(new Company(modelFields)); // THIS TAKES WAAAY TOO LONG. I need to block my UI so that a resubmission cannot happen to the point where its annoying.
```

If there anyway to make the behavior of await DataStore.save(Model); faster? In fact a desirable answer would also be best practices for send queries and saving entries to the DynamoDB.

I am entirely new to web development and am unsure on how to optimized this module. This DataStore code is created by Amazon so while I have access to the library to fix the code, I am unsure where to even begin. Perhaps there is a more optimized way to create entries that is much faster.

I am thinking that this should be theoretically faster because when I use the Amplify Studio GUI, any entry that I add is added instantaneously.

[image]

[image]

What I tried:

Create my own lambda function that my code calls. Not much faster in reality. :(

Play around with the concurrency opperations of react js

Logging everything that is possible so that I can get to the root of the problem.

Comment: You'd want to **profile** the code, but: (a) define "waaaay too long", (b) is there local/remote data that's being synced?

Comment: I clicked it 5 minutes ago. Its still awaiting.

As for if local/remote data that is being synced, I am not sure about this at all. How would I check for this?

Comment: Does it *ever* finish? It should be millis, not even seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your DB operations off the main event loop. i.e. within a hook (`useEffect` or better look into tanstack query), or in response to a user event. Don't put the code in the primary render path so it blocks.

You should always assume your network calls will be slow and build in user interface feedback appropriately.

DataStore goes through AWS's API Gateway and will timeout if the request takes over 30 seconds. How certain are you that there wasn't an error? Check your network tab, console, etc.

You don't need to optimize or bypass DataStore. If you're on your dev machine with a good network connection and it takes more than milliseconds to a second or two then something is wrong.